# Entity Framework 4 relating tables with no foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework for the first time.  The database that I am working with has no foreign key constraints defined (and I cannot change that, integrity is controlled at the app level, out of my hands).

There is a very strong convention in the database -- all PK's are named a specific way, and an FK field has exactly the same name as its corresponding PK.

When I draw a relation with EF, it seems to want to auto-create an FK field in the child table.  Is there any way I can teach EF to infer our relations based upon our convention?

Comment: i don't believe so. EF needs FK's for it's navigational properties. you might have to manually perform the joins using LINQ, or create views and use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to *infer* FKs based on naming conventions, but you can manually add the associations to your model. Associations don't need an underlying FK constraint so you can add the associations to the model only...

---

**Update:** In the latest version of the [Model Comparer for EF4](http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-model-comparer-for-entity.html), I added a feature for inferring FKs and generating associations in EFv4 models based on inferred FK constraints. Blogged about it here: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/12/inferring-foreign-key-constraints-in.html

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you -- I found that the difference was in how I was creating the associations. If I do it by right-clicking the entity, and choosing Add | Association, then I get the undesired behavior. But if I just use the toolbox to create an association by selecting the 2 fields then I get what I want.  It would be nice if I could somehow do this programmatically (plug-in or something), because it is a large database.

Comment: Ok, I'm tempted to take it on. What are the inferrence rules? Matching column name+type?

Comment: Pretty simple rules, with 1 twist. The primary key of a given table will always be named "tablename_K", and if it is a foreign key, it has the same name.  The twist:  table names are plural, key names are singular.  Example:  if the table name is Customers, its pk is Customer_K (and it is designated as a pk).  If I have a child table CustomerInvoices, it will have a column named "Customer_K" that is a foreign key to Customers.

Comment: We use artificial keys, so the pk is always a single column, and it is always the same type.